# Multiple Inner Joins with Order is very slow

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I need some help working out how to make my query more efficient. I'm by no means an expert with SQL but have read a fair bit regarding this but am at the point where I need to ask / discuss.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT
a.seq_num seq_num_a,
a.record_length record_length_a,
b.record_length record_length_b,
c.record_length record_length_c
a.deleted deleted_a,
b.deleted deleted_b,
c.deleted deleted_c
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b
ON a.reference = b.reference
AND a.run_id = b.run_id
INNER JOIN tableC c
ON a.reference = c.reference
AND a.run_id = c.run_id
WHERE a.run_id = 1
)
WHERE deleted_a = 'N'
AND deleted_b = 'N'
AND deleted_c = 'N'
ORDER BY seq_num_a;
```

The query is very slow once I check that deleted = 'N' - even for just tableA. I wrapped the whole query in a SELECT thinking that the subquery would return the dataset, then it would be a simple check and order against that. Note that there is no performance difference with the check within the subquery.

There are indexes against run_id and deleted in all tables, and against the seq_num in tableA. There are roughly 8000 rows in each table.

The query plan

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      |  Name               | Rows  | Bytes | Cost  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                     |     1 |   112 |     7 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                 |                     |     1 |   112 |     7 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                 |                     |     1 |   112 |     3 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                |                     |     1 |    79 |     2 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLEC              |     1 |    33 |     2 |
|*  5 |      INDEX SKIP SCAN           | TABLEC_IDX2         |     1 |       |     2 |
|*  6 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLEA              |     1 |    46 |       |
|*  7 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | TABLEA_IDX5         |     1 |       |       |
|*  8 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | TABLEB              |     1 |    33 |     1 |
|*  9 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | TABLEB_PK           |     1 |       |       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - access("C"."DELETED"='N')
       filter("C"."DELETED"='N')
   6 - filter("A"."REFERENCE"="C"."REFERENCE" AND 
              "A"."RUN_ID"="C"."RUN_ID")
   7 - access("A"."DELETED"='N')
   8 - filter("B"."DELETED"='N')
   9 - access("A"."RUN_ID"="B"."RUN_ID" AND 
              "A"."REFERENCE"="B"."REFERENCE")

Note: cpu costing is off
```

Comment: What is the query plan?  Do the indexes also include the `REFERENCE` column?  Can you quantify "very slow"?  Are we talking hours?  Minutes?  Seconds?  Of the 8000 rows in each table, how many have `DELETED` of 'N'?  How many of the rows in `tableA` have a `RUN_ID` of 1?

Comment: I would also add does deleted contain nulls, or all Y/N? Try posting an explain plan.

Comment: I've looked at explain. Using nested loops. First join is by index rowid, second by Full and the third by index rowid. Reference is also indexed, sorry forgot to mention. 90% of rows are deleted = 'N', 100% rows are runID of 1. Without the check on deleted the query takes 0.3 seconds, with, 115 seconds.

Comment: Ok, so my description of explain wasn't very good. I'm going through the Plan Table, will try to understand how this works and get back to you.

Comment: Please see the plan table output using utlxpls.sql, had to use external pastebin because it won't fit here: http://pastebin.com/eTsZAwkn

Comment: @PaulyM - You can (and should) update your question when you post additional information.  I edited your question to add the query plan you posted.  First off, it appears that the statistics on your objects are incorrect-- when were statistics last gathered?  What is `TABLEC_IDX2` defined as-- it strikes me as highly unlikely that you really want an index skip scan.  How are you measuring the runtime?  Are you measuring the time to retrieve the first row?  Or the time to retrieve the last row?

Comment: Could you try `SELECT /*+ use_hash(a b c) */ * FROM ...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what value the outer select was providing..  depending on the version of oracle the explain plans can be different.  but in older versions I found limiting the data before the joins improved performance dramatically.

Thus starting with A and getting the least amount of records to join to b then to C was MUCH faster than starting with all of A, joining to all of b, and joining to all of C then reducing the results via where clause...  However later verions of the query optimizer took this into account so no gain...  So... what version of oracle?

```
SELECT
a.seq_num seq_num_a,
a.record_length record_length_a,
b.record_length record_length_b,
c.record_length record_length_c
a.deleted deleted_a,
b.deleted deleted_b,
c.deleted deleted_c
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b
  ON a.reference = b.reference
  AND a.run_id = b.run_id
  AND a.deleted = 'N'
  and b.deleted = 'N'
  and a.run_ID = 1
INNER JOIN tableC c
  ON a.reference = c.reference
  AND a.run_id = c.run_id
  and c.deleted = 'N'
ORDER BY seq_num_a;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I implemented this and the query was faster, but I'd have thought too slow for what it is performing. 70seconds down from 115. Only 0.3 seconds with no check on deleted. I am using Oracle9i.

Comment: @PaulyM That increase could be due to caching or other unrelated changes. The key is in the explain plan. Generally speaking, the SQL optimizer doesn't care whether you have your predicate in the join or in the where clause (except for outer joins). I tested cardinality on a known index using both methods and it made no difference to the initial row fetch from each table, and the join method didn't change. Performance is ultimately in the eye of the beholder. Also, do you have current statistics on your schema?

Comment: I agree with Wolf & justin, table stats appear to be off.  The gain you achieved isn't what I expected. @wolf the 9i is the version I was expecting to get a different execution plan on with these changes. > 9, the db engine changed the execution plan to not care where the criteria was placed.